# Как переопределить файл стилей родительской темы?

Tags: php, wordpress

Хочу переопределить файл стилей родительской темы, т.к. в нём для важных селекторов в стилях определено условие `!important`, что категорически мешает.

Подключение стилей в файле родительской темы:

```
/**
 * Enqueue theme scripts and styles.
 */
function maudern_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'maudern-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), Maudern::get_theme_version() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'maudern-main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/styles.css', array(), Maudern::get_theme_version(), 'all' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'maudern_scripts', 100 );
```

Подключение в дочерней:

```
/*
* Load parent and child styles.
*/
function maudern_child_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'maudern-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'maudern-main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/styles.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'maudern-child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( 'maudern-main' ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );

}
add_action(  'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'maudern_child_enqueue_styles', 101 );
```

Как мне правильно это сделать? Через **wp_deregister_style()/wp_register_style()** с последующим **wp_enqueue_style()** это файла уже из дочерней темы?

Answer (score 0):

В общем разобрался. В `functions.php` дочерней темы:

```
/*
* Load parent and child styles.
*/
function maudern_child_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'maudern-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    
    //отключаем вывод стилей родительской темы
    wp_dequeue_style( 'maudern-main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/styles.css' );
    
    //подключаем копию родительского файла стилей из дочерней темы
    wp_enqueue_style( 'maudern-main-2', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/styles.css' );
    
    //меняем зависимость остальных подключаемых стилей
    wp_enqueue_style( 'maudern-child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( 'maudern-main-2' ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );

    //подключаем блок дополнительных стилей из панели настроек
    wp_add_inline_style( 'maudern-main-2', Maudern_Customize::get_options_css() );

}
add_action(  'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'maudern_child_enqueue_styles', 101 );
```